# Why are the outputs of arrayone and two not the same?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int FindMid(int array[], int n) {
  int i;
  int m = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < n - 1 && array[i] > array[i + 1])
      m = i + 1;
  }
  return m;
}

void MySort(int array[], int n) {

  int i = 0;
  int l = 0;
  int t = FindMid(array, n);
  int m = t;
  int k = 0;
  int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n * 2);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp[i] = 0;
  }

  while (l < m && m < n) {
    if (array[l] <= array[m]) {
      temp[k++] = array[l++];
    } else {
      temp[k++] = array[m++];
    }
  }

  while (l < t) {
    temp[k++] = array[l++];
  }
  while (m < n) {
    temp[k++] = array[m++];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = temp[i];
  }

  free(temp);
}

void print_ary(int *pa, int n) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", pa[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int arrayone[13] = {1, 6, 9, 16, 21, 2, 5, 11, 19, 25, 30, 33, 40};
  int arraytwo[13] = {1, 6, 9, 16, 21, 25, 30, 33, 40, 2, 5, 11, 19};
  int a = 13;
  MySort(arrayone, a);
  print_ary(arrayone, a);
  MySort(arraytwo, a);
  print_ary(arraytwo, a);

  return 0;
}
```

According to the code, the output of arrayone and the output of arraytwo should be the same, but different outputs are produced. When passing the while statement for the first time, the value of m should remain added, but it seems that compilation proceeds with the value of m initialized.

`while(m<n){temp[k++]=array[m++]}`

I think this is the problem. How do I fix it?`

**expected(I want)**

```
1 2 5 6 9 11 16 19 21 25 30 33 40
1 2 5 6 9 11 16 19 21 25 30 33 40
```

**output(actually)**

```
1 2 5 6 9 11 16 19 21 2 5 11 19
1 2 5 6 9 11 16 19 21 25 30 33 40
```

```
while (m < n) {
  temp[k++] = array[m++];
}

// Instead of this code

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (temp[k - 1] < array[i]) {
    while (k < n) {
      temp[k++] = array[k++];
    }
  }
}
```

I recompiled using this code and the results were the same. Even if I want to get a hint from chatgpt, it keeps giving the same answer.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to observe why the code does what it does? What does this have to do with C++? It looks like C to me. You better be using C++17, otherwise `temp[k++] = array[k++];` is undefined behaviour due to double increment.

Comment: Nothing in this is C++ except that casting the result of malloc is required in C++ and discouraged in C.

Comment: *Even if I want to get a hint from chatgpt* -- What "hint" were you expecting from an AI-bot?  There are literally an infinite number of ways to write the program -- chatgpt is not a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Start using a debugger. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `while(m<n){temp[k++]=array[m++]} I think this is the problem. How do I fix it?` -- Instead of trying to place everything on one line, why not break up that assignment into multiple lines, so that you know *exactly* when `k` and `m` are incremented?  Given that line, can you be sure *when* or *if* the values of `k` and `m` will have the values you expect?  Also, as a beginner, why would you be compelled to write a line of code like that anyway?  I would expect a beginner to take their time and write multiple lines of code, where they would be sure what values are being used.

Comment: pro-tip: Make use of the `memcpy` function instead of manually copying arrays with your own for-loops.

Comment: Sorry for my TAG,, I firstly use this community, and I'm not useable for some tools and etc.. After asking question in this site, I watch out some rules and review properly about my question once again! thank you for some feedback

Comment: Most readers will not be interested in questions that begin with code dumps and no explanation of the purpose of the calculations. Start by explaining what you attempting to compute and the problem you are having, then present your code, then tie your problem to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Change this:

```
while (l < m && m < n) {
```

To this:

```
while (l < t && m < n) {
```

**Explanation:**

If I read your code correctly, your MySort function takes an array that has two incrementing sequences. Then sorts the array into one unified incrementing sequence.

e.g. `(10,20,30, 1,11,21) => {1,10,11,20,21,30}`

This is your bug:

```
while (l < m && m < n) {
    if (array[l] <= array[m]) {
        temp[k++] = array[l++];
    }
    else {
        temp[k++] = array[m++];
    }
}
```

The code is comparing `l` against `m` (the designated midpoint) on each iteration, but is also using `m` as an iteration index for the right half of the array. Hence `m` is getting incremented on some sequences of the loop, but that `l<m` comparison never expects `m` to change.

You just need to compare `l < t` instead of `l < m`. See above.